# How to get the bitmap/image from WpfImage? UI automation

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, ui-automation

I am implementing UI automation testing using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.

I am using the "Generate Code for Coded UI test" and using the record option. I receive my image as a WpfImage (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls.WpfImage). Is there a way for me to extract out the original image/bitmap from the WpfImage. I tried the CaptureImage() function, but It gives me a screenshot, due to some reasons I need the actual data stored inside the bitmap, Is this possible?

TIA.

Comment: CaptureImage is supposed to use the BoundingRectangle. If it gets the whole screen, it means it detects an incorrect BoundingRectangle. What do you mean by the "actual data inside the bitmap"? can't you extract a portion of the screenshot?

Comment: Suppose I have a 2000 * 2000 image and is displayed at a lower resolution, my capture won't give me the entire data. My query is more like this, can I extract out the Image/BitmapSource/WriteableBitmap from a given WpfImage.

Comment: No in the general case. UI automation works out of process. It has absolutely no idea of the technology it's currently looking at. It could be written in any language and use any imaging technology it want. However if you own the application that's being tested, then you can pass some informations kinda out-of-band, if you invent some protocol between the tester and the tested

Comment: Thanks for the info. So if I get you correctly, I can acquire image data only from the visual perception using a capture (like a screenshot), but not digging into the implementation details.