# UI Automation : Save Automation Element as image?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have an use case as follows,

```
    Process proc = Process.Start("myproc.exe");
    AutomationElement automationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty,
                    proc.Id));
    var imageAutomationElmt = automationElement .FindFirst
            (TreeScope.Descendants, new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition
                (AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "imageData"));
```

The above code fetches me the imageData from my UI. Is there a way for me to save the imageData (of "Image" type) as a file. I tried using the screen capture method, but since I have my app with scroll bar enabled, taking a screen shot doesnt work properly.

Is there a way to save image data to file from automation element of an image?
TIA.

Comment: Rending the entire control to bitmap is very easy, but I am not sure you can actually cast a AutomationElement to a WPF Control. Projects such as snoop have the ability to render interfaces of running applications, it might be worth looking through its code (its open source) to see how they do it. Once you have the object as a control, the rest will be easy

Comment: you already asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054377/how-to-get-the-bitmap-image-from-wpfimage-ui-automation#comment63576279_38054377

Answer (score 1):

If you will use TestStack.White there is a Image class that you can use to get image bytes, the property VisibleImage return Bitmap object and then you can use ImageConverter that will convert bitmap into bytes array and then using simple File.IO and method WriteAllBytes you can save the image into file.

```
       var visibleImage = ChangeIcon.VisibleImage;

        ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
        var bytes =  (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(visibleImage, typeof(byte[]));            

        File.WriteAllBytes($"icon_{new Random().Next()}.bmp", bytes);
```

(the ChangeIcon property type is Image)